# Changing default home directory for Python to start in a different directory

Tags: python

Every time I start iPython, the first thing I **always** immediately change the directory from the default directory, and I would like to know of a way to edit this default starting directory.

Currently, iPython starts in the following directory:

```
In [2]:  os.getcwd()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\Curtis\\Documents\\Python Scripts'
```

And the first thing I always do is:

```
os.chdir('D:')
```

Once in the D: drive, I then use `cd` to navigate my various files and folders.

There must be a way to change the default directory that python starts in so I don't have to do this every time I start iPython.

One thing to note is that I cannot change where python is installed (if that would be an option).

Comment: `getcwd` returns the current working directory ... it should be where ever you launched python from ...

Comment: `cd` into `D:\` first, then do `C:\PythonXX\python.exe` (where `XX` is your python version, eg 27, 33, etc). That should set your current working director to `D:` right at the start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. set PYTHONSTARTUP variable to a desired script. Example:"c:\startup.py"
2. With in startup.py add these lines:

   ```
   import os

   os.chdir('yourdirectory') #example os.chdir("D:\\")
   ```

Comment: can't believe there are only 4 upvotes on this. here is how to add an environment variable in Windows 10, you can use "user variables", no need for "system variables": https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/